# After removing attribute _target, new url is opened under iframe

Tags: typescript, iframe, cypress

Technologies: Cypress/Typescript

I am trying to remove *target _blank* from `<a>` element and to open new url in the same tab, but since that `<a>` is under the iframe, new url is opened in iframe, is there any solution for the issue.

```js
getIframeBody()
  .find('table#emailContainer tr td a')
  .invoke('removeAttr','target')
  .click();
```

Comment: Why is it an issue?

Answer (score 2):

How about you get the href attribute and then just visit it? For example:

```
getIframeBody().find('table#emailContainer tr td a').invoke('attr', 'href').then((href) => {
    cy.visit(href)
    // rest of the test
})
```